# Web Scraping Images: Cannot find 'rel' selector

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm following the tutorial for Automate the Boring Stuff's web-scraping section, and want to scrape the images from https://swordscomic.com/ .

The script should 1) download and parse the html 2) download the comic image 3) click on the "previous comic" button 4) repeat 1 - 3

The script is able to download the first comic, but gets stuck either on hitting the "previous comic" button, or downloading the next comic image.

Possible issues for this may be:

Al's tutorial instructs to find the "rel" selector, but I am unable to find it. I believe this site uses a slightly different format than that site Al's tutorial instructs to scrape. I believe I'm using the correct selector, but the script still crashes.

It may also be the way this site's home landing page contains a comic image, and then each "previous" comic has an additional file-path (in the form of /CCCLXVIII/ or something thereof).

I have tried:

adding the edition # for the comic for the initial page, but that only causes the script to crash earlier.

pointing the "previous button" part of the script to a different selector in the element, but still gives me the "Index out of range" error.

Here is the script as I have it:

```
#! python3
#swordscraper.py - Downloads all the swords comics.

import requests, os, bs4
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\bromp\OneDrive\Desktop\Python')
os.makedirs('swords', exist_ok=True) #store comics in /swords
url = 'https://swordscomic.com/' #starting url

while not url.endswith('#'):

 #Download the page.
print('Downloading page %s...' % url)
res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser') 

#Find the URL of the comic image.
comicElem = soup.select('#comic-image')
if comicElem == []:
    print('Could not find comic image.')
else:
    comicUrl = comicElem[0].get('src')
    comicUrl = "http://" + comicUrl
    if 'swords' not in comicUrl:
        comicUrl=comicUrl[:7]+'swordscomic.com/'+comicUrl[7:]
    #Download the image.
    print('Downloading image %s...' % (comicUrl))
    res = requests.get(comicUrl)
    res.raise_for_status()

#Save the image to ./swords
imageFile = open(os.path.join('swords', os.path.basename(comicUrl)), 'wb')
for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
    imageFile.write(chunk)
imageFile.close()

#Get the Prev button's url.
prevLink = soup.select('a[id=navigation-previous]')[0]
url = 'https://swordscomic.com/' + prevLink.get('href')


print('Done')
```

Here is the output the script does and the particular error message it gives:

```
Downloading page https://swordscomic.com/...
Downloading image http://swordscomic.com//media/Swords363bt.png...
Downloading page https://swordscomic.com//comic/CCCLXII/...
Could not find comic image.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\", line 39, in <module>
    prevLink = soup.select('a[id=navigation-previous]')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

The page is rendered with JavaScript. In particular the link you extract:

```
<a href="/comic/CCCLXII/" id="navigation-previous" class="navigation-button navigation-previous" onclick="COMICS.previousButtonPressed(); return false;"></a>
```

has an onclick() event which presumably links to the next page. In addition the page uses XHR. So your only option is to use a technology that renders JavaScript so try using Selenium or requests-html https://github.com/psf/requests-html.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Isn't the script already using "requests"?

Comment: No requests-html https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/ is different from requests https://pypi.org/project/requests/

Comment: Thinking about it, you may be better with Selenium as you can click the link, requests-html won't trigger the onclick() event.